# How can i add an input in every line of a displayed data?

Tags: python

im trying to have an input in every line of the displayed data.
here are the codes

```
def attendance():
print ("\n\nList of Students\n")
print ("StudNo             StudName       Age      Course    Attendance")
for idx in range(len(studNo)):
    print (" {0:15} {1:10s} {2:10s} {3:10s}".format(studNo[idx], 
studName[idx], Age[idx], Course[idx]))
```

and this is the output
List of Students

StudNo      StudName       Age      Course    Attendance

a1001             Daryl      21         CS
 a1002            Akex       21         CS
 a1003            John       24         CS
 a1004            Jose       22         CS

im creating a simple attendance monitoring system. so im trying to have an input for each line so i can write A for absent or P for present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input function. input("Write your prompt here") will print the prompt and ask the user to write an entry of text. This can get messy with your desired output, so I suggest collecting all attendance information and then printing

---

```
students = ['Kathy','Will','Nayeon']
attendanceRecord = []
for student in students:
    attendance = input("What is "+student+"\'s attendance? ")
    attendanceRecord.append(attendance)

print("\n") # add a space before printing student list
print("Name"+" Attendace")
for i in range(len(students)):
    print(students[i] + " "+ attendanceRecord[i])
```